# Encountering 'Error invoking CFC for gateway file: null

Tags: coldfusion, event-gateway

I'm currently facing an issue with my ColdFusion application where I'm encountering the error message: "Error invoking CFC for gateway file: null." This error was logged inside the eventgateway.log.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
<cfcomponent output="false">
<cffunction name="onIncomingMessage" output="false" returnType="void"> 
<cfargument name="cfEvent" type="struct" required="yes">

<cflog file="test" text="Here!">

<cftry>
    <cfscript> 
        if(not structKeyExists(arguments.cfEvent.data, "file")) 
        arguments.cfEvent.Data.file="defaultEventLog"; 

        if(not structKeyExists(arguments.cfEvent.data, "type")) 
        arguments.cfEvent.Data.type="info"; 
    </cfscript>

    <cflog file="application" text="Your log message here">
    
    <!--- If an error occurs, the control will jump to the cfcatch block --->
    <cfcatch type="any">
        <!--- Handle the error --->
        <cflog file="application" text="An error occurred: #cfcatch.message#">
        <cfoutput>
            An error occurred: #cfcatch.message#
        </cfoutput>
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
</cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

And this is the code trying to invoke the event gateway.

```
<cftry> 
    <cfscript> 
        status = false; 
        cfEvent = structNew(); 
        cfEvent.message = "Replace me with a variable with data to log"; 
        status = SendGatewayMessage("file", cfEvent); 
        if (status IS true) WriteOutput('Event Message "#cfEvent.Message#" has been sent.'); 
    </cfscript>
    
    <!--- If an error occurs, the control will jump to the cfcatch block --->
    <cfcatch type="any">
        <!--- Handle the error --->
        <cflog file="application" text="An error occurred: #cfcatch.message#">
        <cfoutput>
            An error occurred: #cfcatch.message#
        </cfoutput>
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

I've checked my code and configurations, but I'm still unable to pinpoint the exact cause of this error. Could anyone help me please?

Comment: How is the gateway configured in the CF admin?